# Using PUT to receive an xml file in webpy

Tags: python, web.py

I am trying to receive an xml file through PUT in web.py, it is not working.Can any one explain what is the issue in the below code

```
import web

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)

class index:
    def PUT(self):
        postdata = web.data().read()
        fout = open('/home/test/Desktop/e.xml','w')
        fout.write(postdata)
        fout.close()
        return "Hello, world!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

I am getting this is terminal

```
"HTTP/1.1 PUT /doc.xml" - 404 Not Found
```

I use curl to upload the xml

```
curl -o log.out -H "Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" -T doc.xml "http://0.0.0.0:8760"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import web

urls = ( '/upload', 'index')

class index:
    def PUT(self):
        datta = web.data()
        with open("another.xml", "w") as f:
            f.write(datta)
        return "hello"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

with this curl

```
curl -T somexml.xml http://0.0.0.0:8080/upload
```

worked for me. I needed to change url because curl behaved strange. Or maybe it seemed to me. but somehow this code won't work with "/" as a url.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong `curl` option.

If you want your file content in the request body, you should use `-d` instead of `-T`

```
curl -o log.out -H "Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" -d doc.xml "http://0.0.0.0:8760"
```

EDIT:

Anyway, this will transform your `curl` into a POST request. To keep it as PUT, use `-X PUT`

```
curl -X PUT -o log.out -H "Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" -d doc.xml "http://0.0.0.0:8760"
```